# Function to obtain the name of the highest scorer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set that lists in Column A names and in column B the scores for each. I am using the MAX function to obtain the highest score but I want to also obtain the name associated with the highest score. I don’t think I can use VLOOKUP as the name column comes before the score column. Any tricks to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `SORT()` function then use-

```
=INDEX(SORT(A2:B5,2,-1),1)
```

[image]

Otherwise `INDEX/MATCH()` combination like-

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(D4,B2:B5,0))
```

Or use `MAX()` function as lookup value for `MATCH()` function.

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(MAX(B2:B5),B2:B5,0))
```

[image]

Comment: ‘s  If you can use SORT() you also can use FILTER(), maybe this will ne a better choise, maybe there are the same scores for different names?!

Comment: @Chris Yap, for multiple records `FILTER()` would be good choice.